# Code checking as-you-type C++

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, ide

Visual Studio is capable of reporting errors and warnings "as you type" in the Error List View;

Is there any C++ IDE for Linux capable of behaving as Visual Studio does (With the same level of speed/accuracy)?

This boosts the speed of the development drastically.

Comment: What do you mean in real time? When you run the code?

Comment: Those aren't compiler errors, they are *runtime* errors. And it can be done for e.g. C# because it is, in essence, an interpreted language.

Comment: My guess is that with "in real-time" you mean "as soon as you type"? Because I can not see an advantage of compile errors during runtime (vs compile-time of non-JIT compiler prior to running it).

Comment: [eclipse](http://eclipse.org/ide/) does various code checks while you type..

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I made the question more understandable.

Comment: Yes, most IDEs should do that, but finding one which fits your needs is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Galik Eclipse needs a deep and precise configuration to be able to achieve it just partially, in my experience, most of the time, it is flagging non-errors and/or not flagging real errors.

Comment: @leemes Is that relying on the IDE in .NET/Mono rather than feedback from the compiler/interpreter? Because it's really precise and I never found anything similar for a C++ IDE.

Comment: @Joachim Nope, sorry. C# is a compiled language (code --compiler--> MSIL --JIT--> machine code). Uno: JetBrains is preparing a ReSharper for C++, I don't know what features will be available at launch, but the C# version does wonders.

Comment: this is possible, but afaik there are no real JIT compilers for C++(there is one interpreter) so you will have to write one for yourself

Comment: @Uno The Visual Studio IDE has a *very* good checker for C++, it's called *IntelliSense* and reports errors in very human-friendly form (compared to those g++ error messages, for example...). Visual Studio is one of the best IDEs, for C++ as well as for other languages. And I have to say this as someone who usually hates MS. ;)

Comment: @leemes Looks like they're not planning to port VS to Linux.

Comment: wine can run .exe compiled on windows with very low drop in code speed

Comment: @Creris Would be really great if I could code gtkmm/Linux applications in VS, but I'm not sure how hard it would be to set up (assuming I will also need a virtual machine to have both the environments running). The drop in speed and potential incompatibility would be quite high for a big project I believe.

Comment: One more thing to clear the confusion: code inspections have **nothing** to do with the language using a JIT (as an example, C# can be used without a JIT - see [ngen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf.aspx)).

Comment: @Uno not really, even games can run on wine on Linux that are compiled for Windows with pretty much the same performance as on Windows. Wine does a good job on this

Comment: @Creris About the performances, it's true; But games in Wine are far from being "crash-free" and I don't really know what might happen, but I see potentially a disaster in compiling gtkmm in a Windows binary and then running it with Wine. (Talking GUI-wise)

Comment: @Uno My comment about Visual Studio was because you said you don't know of a similar feature for a C++ IDE when you were taking about what it does with C#. (Just wanted to emphasize that Visual Studio is not only useful for .NET development but also for (standard) C++). And you were not asking for an IDE for linux. But if you need that, have a look at QtCreator.

Comment: @leemes As I said "as Visual Studio .NET does", I meant a different IDE, but I could have been more clear, I'll modify the question. I didn't know that VS had this feature for NON-CIL languages like native C++.

Comment: I think I might end up writing the code in Visual Studio and compiling it into a virtual machine with Linux.

Answer (score 3):

If you know IntelliSense in the C# IDE then you're not too far from a C++ IDE that implements this, the Visual C++ IDE does this as well.  Modeling this feature as a JIT compiler isn't very accurate, it is simply the front-end of a C++ compiler.  Minus the back-end, the code generator, that doesn't happen until you actually build the project.

Sounds simple, it is nonetheless a pretty non-trivial thing to do well.  Primary implementation problems are doing it fast enough, in the background while the programmer is typing.  And dealing with code that is almost always in an uncompilable state since the programmer is busy editing.  Common front-ends in regular C++ compilers are not typically fit for that job.  They are not fast enough and don't particularly deal with uncompilable code all that well, often generating a flurry of additional uninteresting errors that were induced by a single mistake.

Microsoft used to use their own parser to do this but gave up on it.  The Edison Design Group are the specialists in this kind of tooling, famous for one for being the only ones that ever created a C++ compiler that completely implemented the C++03 language specification.  EDG just sells the front-end, they leave the back-end to the implementer.  VS2010 was the first VS version that started using EDG's.  Not entirely trouble-free btw, in a few corner cases the EDG parser disagrees with the Visual C++ compiler.

This feature is not otherwise widely available.  It is just plain expensive and hard to maintain, especially with the rapid changes in C++ as of late.  Last I heard (been a while), EDG asks you to plunk down $50,000 before they even start talking to you, there probably is a royalty payment involved as well.  It surely costs Microsoft a wholeheckofalot more, they also need to support the C++/CLI and C++/CX language extensions.  Well, that's what you're paying for.

Comment: Thank you, was really useful to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

KDevelop, QtCreator, XCode and many other editors offer this feature. And more will come, as nowadays it's rather trivial to implement in some way based on Clang.

Comment: It is also "simple" to implement with recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) to customize it.